# Apps Script TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendRow')

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm try to run a web app form using Apps Script. But I'm when getting an error when try to use and submit the web app form: **TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendRow')!**

This is the back end code I used (code.gs)

```
var folderID = ""; //the "root" with folder ID to upload files to a specific folder
var sheetName = ""; //the "Data" with the data sheet name

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function uploadFiles(formObject) {
  try {
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var fileUrl = "";
    var fileName = "";

    //Upload file if exists and update the file url
    if (formObject.myFile.length > 0) {
      var blob = formObject.myFile;
      var file = folder.createFile(blob);
      file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.first_name);
      fileUrl = file.getUrl();
      fileName = file.getName();
    } else{
      fileUrl = "Record saved without a file";
    }

    //Saving records to Google Sheet
    sheet.appendRow([
      formObject.first_name,
      formObject.last_name,
      formObject.gender,
      formObject.dateOfBirth,
      formObject.email,
      formObject.phone,
      fileName,
      fileUrl,
      Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")]);
    
    // Return the URL of the saved file
    return fileUrl;
    
  } catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

This is the html code I used (Index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">

        <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
          <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Contact Details</p>

          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Your full name..."/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <p>Gender</p>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="male">Male</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="female">Female</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of Birth</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
          </div>

           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="FormControlFile">Photo</label> 
            <input name="myFile" class="form-control-file" type="file" id="FormControlFile" />
           </div>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div id="output"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is the Javascript code I used (JavaScript.html)

```
<script>
  function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

  function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).withFailureHandler(onFailure).uploadFiles(formObject);
  }

  function updateUrl(url) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    if(isValidURL(url)){
      div.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><a href="' + url + '">File uploaded successfully!</a></div>';
      document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }else{
      //Show warning message if file is not uploaded or provided
      div.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+ url +'!</div>';
    }
  }

  function onFailure(error) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+ error.message +'!</div>';
  }

  function isValidURL(string) {
    var res = string.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
    return (res !== null);
  }
</script>
```

Anyone can help with this issue and what went wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your showing script and error message, I guessed the following confirmation points. Please confirm them.

1. From your error message of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendRow')!`, I'm worried that about your showing script, the value of `var sheetName = "";` might be invalid value. For example, I think that when you directly use `var sheetName = "";` or unexistence sheet name, such an error occurs. Please confirm this again. And also, please confirm your current value of `folderID`, again.
2. If you confirmed that your `sheetName` is a valid value (the sheet name is correct), I'm worried that your latest script might be correctly reflected in your Web Apps. So, please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
   - You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Note:

- When I tested your showing script using valid values of `folderID` and `sheetName`, I confirmed that the submitted values could be appended to the Spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: Hi Tanaike,

You're right,  the value in the var sheetName was incorrect. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, is there a way to give access to input form ONLY via web app and RESTRICT input directly in Google sheet ?

Comment: @Jack About your new question of `Also, is there a way to give access to input form ONLY via web app and RESTRICT input directly in Google sheet ?`, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Ok sure, I'll post the question asap

Comment: I just post it, pls check